# Access two tables inside tr tag of an outer table, which in turn contains tables and other elements like select list, text area

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

My need is to identify the table and check the values of each select list for particular Problem name and their corresponding notes values.

Here I found that the question itself got split into two tables and I'm facing difficulty in accessing them.

My HTML structure looks like the below.

```
    <table class="dataentry">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td width="50%">
            <table class="genetichxtable entirewidth">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Y/N</th>
                        <th>Notes</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Huntington's Chorea</td>
                        <td class="nowrap">
                            <select name="GSANS{1}{ANSWERYN}" questionid="1" section="GENETICHX" type="SELECT">
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option value="Y">Yes</option>
                                <option value="N">No</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td class="nowrap">
                            <textarea  name="GSANS{1}{ANSWERNOTES}"  type="TEXTAREA">
                            </textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>History of Hepatitis</td>
                        <td class="nowrap">
                            <select name="GSANS{2}{ANSWERYN}" questionid="2" section="GENETICHX" type="SELECT">
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option value="Y">Yes</option>
                                <option value="N">No</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td class="nowrap"><textarea  name="GSANS{2}{ANSWERNOTES}"  type="TEXTAREA"></textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Intellectual Disability/Autism</td>
                        <td class="nowrap">
                            <select name="GSANS{5}{ANSWERYN}" questionid="5" section="GENETICHX" type="SELECT">
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option value="Y">Yes</option>
                                <option value="N">No</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td class="nowrap"><textarea  name="GSANS{5}{ANSWERNOTES}"  type="TEXTAREA"></textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td width="50%">
            <table class="genetichxtable entirewidth">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Y/N</th>
                        <th>Notes</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Thalassemia (Italian, Greek, Mediterranean, Or Asian Background): MCV &lt; 80</td>
                        <td class="nowrap">
                            <select name="GSANS{4}{ANSWERYN}" questionid="4" section="GENETICHX" type="SELECT">
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option value="Y">Yes</option>
                                <option value="N">No</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td class="nowrap"><textarea  name="GSANS{4}{ANSWERNOTES}"  type="TEXTAREA"></textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Congenital Heart Defect</td>
                        <td class="nowrap">
                            <select name="GSANS{3}{ANSWERYN}" questionid="3" section="GENETICHX" type="SELECT">
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option value="Y">Yes</option>
                                <option value="N">No</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td class="nowrap"><textarea  name="GSANS{3}{ANSWERNOTES}"  type="TEXTAREA"></textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to iterate over the table to select values for select_list from dropdown and enter notes.Is there any way to automate this using WATIR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each question is encapsulated in a row - `tr` element. However, some of the rows are not rows - ex the `tr` containing the 2 child tables and the `tr` containing column headers. What differentiates the question rows is that contain a select list (ie a question).

You can find the question rows by finding the inner rows with select lists:

```
outer_tr = browser.table(class: 'dataentry').tr
questions = outer_tr.trs.select { |tr| tr.select.exists? }
```

While less Watir-like, this can be more succinctly written using XPath:

```
questions = browser.trs(xpath: '//table[@class="dataentry"]//tr[./td/select]')
```

Regardless of which of the above approaches you use, you now have each question row in a collection. This allows you to iterate over each row and find the title, select list and notes field that are for the same question. The following iterates over each question:

```
questions.each do |tr|
  # The data/fields of interest for the row
  title = tr.td.text
  select = tr.select
  notes = tr.textarea

  # Do stuff with the fields
  p title
  select.select('Yes')
  notes.set('some note')
end
```

If you are looking to set a specific question, I assume by the title, you can iterate over the questions using the `find` method. This will return the specific row related to question. For example, the following finds the question related to "History of Hepatitis". You can see the select/textarea for the question are the correct related fields (ie question 2).

```
question = questions.find { |q| q.td.text == 'History of Hepatitis' }
p question.td.text
#=> "History of Hepatitis"
p question.select.name
#=> "GSANS{2}{ANSWERYN}"
p question.textarea.name
#=> "GSANS{2}{ANSWERNOTES}"
```

Note that if you are using the page-object gem, the nested element method names are different. The following shows iterating through each question in the page-object syntax:

```
outer_tr = table_element(class: 'dataentry').row_element
questions = outer_tr.row_elements.select { |tr| tr.select_list_element.exists? }

questions.each do |question|
  # The data/fields of interest for the row
  title = question.cell_element.text
  select = question.select_list_element
  notes = question.text_area_element

  # Do stuff with the fields
  p title
  select.select('Yes')
  notes.value = 'some note'
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Justin ko, It's working fine with fewer modifications for my requirement. But while using tr in my framework it is showing **DEPRECATION WARNING *** You are calling a method named tr**. Later I changed it to cell_element where it again shows deprecation warning for trs. 

Is there any way to get rid of this?

Comment: Which framework are you using? If it is the page-object gem, then the `tr` should be replaced with `row_element` and `trs` should be replaced by `row_elements`.

Comment: I'm using  page object gem only. When  replaced trs with row_elements, I'm getting **NoMethodError in 'Execute': undefined method `exists?' for #<Enumerator:0x00000006cc0960>",**

Comment: You'll need to make sure to update all of the nested element calls. Based on the exception, it sounds like you did not switch `select` to `select_list_element`. I have updated the answer to show the iteration example using the page-object syntax.

Comment: Perfect. It's working fine after updating all the nested elements as you mentioned. Thanks a lot @Justin ko :)